Error in configuaration Spring MVC with dynamic project in eclipse
enter image description here
enter image description here
I am configuration a Dynamic Project java spring. The project is connect from eclipse to tomcat sever. Bun in project i have file logser-servlet.xml and web.xml. I don't know what thay are user for. When i click on log-servlet.xml then eclip reports an error as above.
Please guide to me. What are logser-servlet.xml and web.xml files for? How to fix thay error. Thank you so much!
I searched on youtube an google. I want to complete solve the problem.
